# Keep doubled columns which differ in only 2 letters in a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R which consists of around 100 columns. Most of the columns are doubled but differ in 2 letters. I want to keep these columns and delete those columns which are not doubled.

Here is an example:

```
234-rgz SK    234-rgz PV    556-gft SK    456-hjk SK    456-hjk PV
```

The Output should be:

```
234-rgz SK    234-rgz PV    456-hjk SK    456-hjk PV
```

All columns have the same naming conventions. A number starting from 2 to 150 then a "-" after this 4 or 5 letters, then a space and then "SK" or "PV". I thought of using regular expression but then I don't solving the problem how I get rid of those single columns. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` on the column names after removing the suffix part.  The output will be logical index which can be used to `subset` the original dataset.

```
v1 <- colnames(df1)
v2 <- sub('\\s+[^ ]+$', '', v1)
indx <- duplicated(v2)|duplicated(v2, fromLast=TRUE)
v1[indx]
#[1] "234-rgz SK" "234-rgz PV" "456-hjk SK" "456-hjk PV"
```

To subset the columns in the dataframe,

```
df1[indx]
```

Or another option is splitting the column names string to substring and use `grep` to match the substring that have a frequency >1

```
 tbl <- table(unlist(strsplit(v1, '\\s+.*')))
 df1[grep(paste(names(tbl)[tbl>1], collapse="|"), v1)]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:9, 5*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=5, 
 dimnames=list(NULL, c('234-rgz SK',  '234-rgz PV' ,   '556-gft SK', 
   '456-hjk SK' ,   '456-hjk PV') )) )
```